# Prove that regions formed by a planar map vertices even degree can be colored with two colors such that no two neighboring regions have the same color

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, solution-verification, coloring, planar-graphs

> Prove that regions formed by a planar map all of whose vertices have
> even degree can be colored with two colors such that no two
> neighboring regions have the same color.

I would like a proof using induction. This problem seems too much abstract to me, I can't think in a way to apply the reduction step, there's so much ways of drawing an edge for this kind of example.

Comment: Hint: look at the dual graph and apply a characterization of bipartite graphs in terms of parity of cycles.

Comment: @RandyMarsh how do you use the fact there's no odd degree vertex to conclude there's no odd cycle in the dual?

Answer (score 1):

We prove by induction on the number of regions. If there is only one region, it can be colored with two colors.

To begin the reduction step, start from a vertex and remove one of the regions by continuing the path until reaching again. Since we traversed a cycle, two edges were removed from each vertex, and the reduced planar map maintains the desired property, vertices still have even degree. Thus, based on the induction hypothesis, it can be colored with two colors.

Upon adding the removed region again, some regions are inside the added region, and some are outside. Reverse the color of the inside regions and leave the outside ones the same as before. This results in a valid coloring, as if the boundry edge is inside the added region, then previously two regions adjacent to it had a valid coloring, and the colors are now just reversed. If the boundry is due to the added region, then the color of the inside is reversed while the outside remains the same. Thus, the proof is complete.